# How to make UIPageViewController show current and next cell simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

My app use UIPageViewController to implement swipe card like this
[image]

Now I would like to implement swipe card like below, it shows part of next cell
[image]

Is there any way using UIPageViewController to implement swipe card like the second image?

Answer (score -1):

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingView: View {

    var fruits: [Fruit] = fruitsData

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(fruits[0...5]) { item in
                FruitCardView(fruit: item)
            } // Loop
        } // Tab
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .padding(.vertical, 20)
    }
}

struct OnboardingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnboardingView(fruits: fruitsData)
    }
}
```

**You can try this here is a tabview which have 5 card that can be swipe there is a FruitCardView(fruit: item) is just a card view which had image and text.

------------------   or -------------------

If you are working in swift then you can use collection view there scroll is enable in horizontal axis**